# Can't call global javascript functions from android phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have a global file functions.js with global javascript functions which are called from other javascripts. Why is not this working on my android phone?

Functions are defined like this in functions.js

```
function function_name(){
    alert("test");
}
```

And called like in the other javascript files.

```
function_name();
```

Is there another way to deal with global javascript functions to get it working on android?

Comment: Are you talking about an hybrid app (i.e. Apache Cordova, Titanium...) or it's just a Web site?

Comment: Then , I'm sure there should be other issue...

Comment: If turned out that it was a function defined with a parameter like: function function_name( parameter = "" ){ ... } which made it impossible to call functions from functions.js. Android seems to be very strict interpreting javascript syntax and if there is an error it can break the whole script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a function defined with a parameter like:

```
function example(parameter = ""){
    ...code...
}
```

which made it impossible to call functions.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to call a global function that is delcared in a `.js` file, from a different HTML file, then you must include the .js file in the `<script>` tag

```
/* Your code.js should look like: */

function function_name(){
    alert('test');
}
```

then

```
<!-- and your HTML file should look like -->
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <SCRIPT SRC='code.js'></SCRIPT>
  <script>
     // you may call your globar function here:
     function_name();
  </scirpt>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <script>
      //you can also call your function anywhere here:
      function_name();
  </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I'ts already included and it's working in browsers. Thank you for your answer though.